# Robocopy sending email, attachment, appending file name

Tags: powershell, outlook, robocopy

I am using robocopy to backup one hard drive to another below is the code that I am using:

```
robocopy "\\server_location\XXXX" "\\local_location\xxxx" /copyall /TEE /S /r:1 /ndl /xc /xo /xn /log+:"C:\desktop\log.TXT"

START mailto:myemail.job.com?subject=Ovl%%2Reportˆ&body=Test,%%0D%%0A%%0D%%0AHere%%20is%%20is%%the%%20ovl%%20report.%%0D%%0A%%0D%%0ABye
```

I need to be able to do a couple of things:

1. email the text file (powershell?) automatically through outlook.
2. When comparing files if the time stamp is different, append the destination file name, and copy over the file from the source.

Comment: I've tried different scenerios and i can get outlook to open, but it doesnt ttach a file nor does it send an email. I believe this is a security featyre of outlook. As far as the appending file havent tried anything.

Comment: Why don't you use `Send-MailMessage` CmdLet to send your mail ?

Comment: For the second point: do you mean to create a list of changed (and thus copied) files into the email? Ie. you want to transform/re-format the `robocopy` output for the email?

Answer (score 2):

So here is a script I've used for a lot of my robocopy jobs. I'm not sure if it fits your "send email through outlook" as it's just doing an SMTP, it's not actually hooking in to Outlook to do it. The script is a Powershell 2.0 script, and remember only Server 2008R2 and Windows Vista+ have the /MT option, which is bad to use with the /TEE option. Script is at the bottom of the post.

For the second point you have, I think you might want two different scripts, one that specifically ignores timestamps, and then another that would include the timestamp difference files, which if ran directly after the first should be about right. This would be with the /XO switch which is "/XO : eXclude Older - if destination file exists and is the same date or newer than the source - don’t bother to overwrite it."

Other options that might help you in scripting that out are:

/XC | /XN : eXclude Changed | Newer files
/XL : eXclude "Lonely" files and dirs (present in source but not destination) This will prevent any new files being added to the destination.
/XX : eXclude "eXtra" files and dirs (present in destination but not source) This will prevent any deletions from the destination. (this is the default)

```
#*=============================================
#* Base variables
#*=============================================

$SourceFolder = "C:\SourceFolder"
$DestinationFolder = "C:\DestinationFolder"
$Logfile = "C:\Robocopy.log"
$Subject = "Robocopy Results: Copy Purpose - Location to Location"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.server.com"
$Sender = "Server <email@address.com>"
$Recipients = "User1 <email@address.com>"
$Admin = "Admin <email@address.com>"
$SendEmail = $True
$IncludeAdmin = $True
$AsAttachment = $False

#*=============================================
#* GMAIL variables
#*=============================================
#$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
#$cred = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
# Add "-UseSsl -Credential $cred" to the Send-MailMessage

#*=============================================
#* SCRIPT BODY
#*=============================================

# Change robocopy options as needed. ( http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html )
Robocopy $SourceFolder $DestinationFolder /MIR /R:2 /W:5 /LOG:$Logfile /NP /NDL

# The following attempts to get the error code for Robocopy
# and use this as extra infromation and email determination.
# NO OTHER CODE BETWEEN THE SWITCH AND THE ROBOCOPY COMMAND
Switch ($LASTEXITCODE)
{
16
{
$exit_code = "16"
$exit_reason = "***FATAL ERROR***"
#$IncludeAdmin = $False
#$SendEmail = $False
}
8
{
$exit_code = "8"
$exit_reason = "**FAILED COPIES**"
#$IncludeAdmin = $False
#$SendEmail = $False
}
4
{
$exit_code = "4"
$exit_reason = "*MISMATCHES*"
$IncludeAdmin = $False
#$SendEmail = $False
}
2
{
$exit_code = "2"
$exit_reason = "EXTRA FILES"
$IncludeAdmin = $False
#$SendEmail = $False
}
1
{
$exit_code = "1"
$exit_reason = "Copy Successful"
$IncludeAdmin = $False
#$SendEmail = $False
}
0
{
$exit_code = "0"
$exit_reason = "No Change"
$SendEmail = $False
$IncludeAdmin = $False
}
default
{
$exit_code = "Unknown ($LASTEXITCODE)"
$exit_reason = "Unknown Reason"
#$SendEmail = $False
$IncludeAdmin = $False
}
}

# Modify the subject with Exit Reason and Exit Code
$Subject += " : " + $exit_reason + " EC: " + $exit_code

# Test log file size to determine if it should be emailed
# or just a status email
If ((Get-ChildItem $Logfile).Length -lt 25mb)
{
If ($IncludeAdmin)
{
If ($AsAttachment)
{
Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -To $Recipients -Cc $Admin -Subject $Subject -Body "Robocopy results are attached." -Attachment $Logfile -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
} Else {
Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -To $Recipients -Cc $Admin -Subject $Subject -Body (Get-Content $LogFile | Out-String) -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}
} Else {
If ($AsAttachment)
{
Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -To $Recipients -Subject $Subject -Body "Robocopy results are attached." -Attachment $Logfile -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
} Else {
Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -To $Recipients -Subject $Subject -Body (Get-Content $LogFile | Out-String) -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}
}
} Else {
# Creat the email body from the beginning and end of the $Logfile
$Body = "Logfile was too large to send." + (Get-Content $LogFile -TotalCount 15 | Out-String) + (Get-Content $LogFile | Select-Object -Last 13 | Out-String)
# Include Admin if log file was too large to email
Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -To $Recipients -Cc $Admin -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
#Exclude Admin if log file was too large to email
#Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -To $Recipients -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}

#*=============================================
#* END OF SCRIPT: Copy-RobocopyAndEmail.ps1
#*=============================================
```